# selecting a row value from datagrid should update inside datagrid using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a datagrid inside a datagrid like following:

```
<asp:DataGrid id="GV1" Runat="server" >
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Item ID" DataField="item_id" Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Item Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>  
                                <asp:LinkButton id="lbitemName" runat="server"  class="list_review" OnClientClick="return false;"/>                                     
                                <asp:DataGrid id="GV2" Runat="server" AllowPaging="true" UseAccessibleHeader="True" CssClass="list_info" style="display:none;">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="User Name" DataField="user_fullname"></asp:BoundColumn>

                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:DataGrid>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
       </Columns>
                                </asp:DataGrid>
```

So when you click on linkbutton "lbitemName" then take the item_id value and bind the GV2 with that item_id   in Jquery.Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are needing , would help if you provided html and better description but try this

```
 $('.list_review').click(function(){
    var nextID=$(this).next().attr('id');
    alert( nextID);
});
```